# Screen Recording is Very Choppy

Tags: desktop-recording, obs-studio, video-recording

I've tried many apps to record my screen on Ubuntu, such as Kazam and OBS Studio, but they all result in the output file being choppy and laggy. There are no problems with audio, just the video. At first I thought I didn't have enough RAM, but I have 8 GB and I'm pretty sure that's enough RAM to record my screen .

It gets the most choppy when there is a lot going on onscreen (like if I'm gaming or using a program that does a lot onscreen, like Blender). I've tried fiddling with the settings in the screen recorders but nothing seems to work.

---

### More info on my system

Neofetch:

```
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               alex@alex-Inspiron-3793 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ----------------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: Inspiron 3793 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.11.0-46-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 2 hours, 50 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2788 (dpkg), 24 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: zsh 5.8 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Mojave-dark 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Mojave-light [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Sweet-Blue-Filled [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel i7-1065G7 (8) @ 3.900GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: Intel Iris Plus Graphics G7 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 2864MiB / 7722MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

GNOME Settings App:

[image]

---

I don't know if screen recording worked on Windows when I origionally got this computer, because I personally hate Windows and wiped the disk right away to get Ubuntu ASAP. :P

I have an old MacBook Air in the house that specs that aren't as good as mine, and recording the screen is completely fine. (For clarification, the MacBook doesn't have Ubuntu on it.)

Am I not using the right drivers for something? Am I missing something? Wrong settings in recording app?

If there isn't a solution for some reason, I'd accept an answer that tells me *why* there isn't a solution and *why* the screen recording is choppy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With my 11th gen Intel laptops (like my ThinkPad P1), I've had nothing but issues with screen recording. It's choppy, and I've tried everything (without any success). With my AMD laptops (Ryzen 7 4800H and another with the Ryzen 7 5825U), screen recording is pixel perfect and smooth. Screen recording worked perfectly on my older ThinkPads (with the U series CPUs). I think there's a big issue with the 10th and 11th gen Intel CPUs in regards to video/screen recording.